# AWS Alarm is always 'in alarm' after deleting an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have set up **2 CloudWatch alarms** on a queue metric. Once a batch of files have been uploaded to an S3 bucket, the alarms watch out for a predefined value (in this case it is 10), and launch/terminate an instance accordingly so that my application auto-scales appropriately.

However, since one of the alarms terminates instances once the number of messages on my queue is less than 10, at one point it constantly is in a state of '**ALARM**' as the messages available are less than 10.

Is there any simple way I can fix this?

Comment: What exactly is the metric you use, what are the datapoints, at what point do you want to alarm, when do you want to go back to an ok state?

Comment: The metric is "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible", datapoints are 1, I want to alarm when 10 or less queue messages are available. I want the alarm to go back to an OK state once it terminates an instance for example.